# Why I can't reference global function by globalThis?

Tags: node.js

`a.mjs`

```js
async function a() {}

console.log(globalThis["a"]);
```

The result is `undefined` if I run the above by `node a.mjs`. But in the repl result is `[AsyncFunction: a]`.

I expected the repl behavior. What am I missing here?

Comment: const globalThis = this;

Comment: @jkalandarov `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'a')`
What did you mean?

Comment: In runtime, the state of the module is bound to `this`. You can assign `this` to a variable at the top level and assign properties to `this` then use those properties in other modules.